# Changing of selection in manually bound ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

I fill the combobox with the below method and when I change the selection it's changed in all the Comboboxes why?

```
PowerProjectDBLinqDataContext dataContext =new PowerProjectDBLinqDataContext();
IEnumerable<Winding_Building_typeCombo> ls = dataContext.Winding_Building_typeCombos.ToList();
ComboBox cbx;
           for (int i = 1; i <= windingCount; i++)
           {
               cbx=((ComboBox)WindingPanel.Controls["winding" + i].Controls["cbxWindingBildingType" + i]);
               cbx.ValueMember = "id";
               cbx.DisplayMember = "value";
               cbx.DataSource = ls;
           }
```

Comment: Is someone going to die? Why is THIS more important than other questions?

Comment: hehehe...!!!??? cute answer ..........!!!???
no one said that it's more important I said that it's urgent because I need it for today delivery in 3 hrs

Comment: @Mario: Well, that's your problem, not ours.

Comment: I didn't say other than that and your not forced to answer .
please stop this Noise  of unhelpful comments
thanks for your coorporation

Comment: @Mario: We will, if you stop acting like someone is going to DIE!

Comment: leppie, you are the one being irate. Why are you so uptight, its not as if someone is going to OMGZDI3

Comment: @John Nicholas: The post used to be URGENTZ in the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer is probably not in this code.;

I imagine its because all iof the combo boxes are using the same reference.

you have probably done something like this

```
var combo = new ComboBox();
ComboBox cb1 = combo;
ComboBox cb2 = combo;
ComboBox cb3 = combo;
```

Edit: oops yeah as the other guy said, you are setting them all the use the same data context. Ie when you change the selected value in the datacontext they will all update to reflect their context - ie to select the same row.

```
cbx.DataSource = ls;
```

this line is setting them all to the same thing. you need to take a copy of the datacontext in each case so that each combo points to a unique datacontext.

Try this

```
PowerProjectDBLinqDataContext dataContext =new PowerProjectDBLinqDataContext(); 
ComboBox cbx; 
           for (int i = 1; i <= windingCount; i++) 
           { 
               IEnumerable<Winding_Building_typeCombo> ls = dataContext.Winding_Building_typeCombos.ToList(); 
               cbx=((ComboBox)WindingPanel.Controls["winding" + i].Controls["cbxWindingBildingType" + i]); 
               cbx.ValueMember = "id"; 
               cbx.DisplayMember = "value"; 
               cbx.DataSource = ls; 
           }
```

Comment: this will cost me time and the memory maybe will be full because I have 10 combobox and a lot of data

Comment: premature optomisation is the root of all evil.

Comment: How about you get it to work before you worry about how it runs? you will have to do some work. all i am doing is answering your question. Implement sopmething in the winding to do do a memberwise clone on the data to copy in it.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have only one instance of cbx control. So each time you are binding your cbx to a data source you are actually overwriting currently existing data binding, and eventually your control will be bound to the last data source only.

Comment: the Combobox are all well fill and in plus I try to put 
"cbx=new Combobox()" in the For but it not work

Comment: Please provide us with code that shows creation of the object and adding it to the parent control.

Comment: I created the object visually drag and drop in the visual studio

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method and it's working  I create an image of the list in the place of the Context to save time and memory

---

```
PowerProjectDBLinqDataContext dataContext =new PowerProjectDBLinqDataContext();
            IEnumerable<Winding_Building_typeCombo> ls = dataContext.Winding_Building_typeCombos.ToList();
            ComboBox cbx;
           for (int i = 1; i <= windingCount; i++)
           {
               IEnumerable<Winding_Building_typeCombo> lsCopy = new List<Winding_Building_typeCombo>(ls);
               cbx=((ComboBox)WindingPanel.Controls["winding" + i].Controls["cbxWindingBildingType" + i]);
               cbx.DataSource = lsCopy;
               lsCopy = null;
               cbx.ValueMember = "id";
               cbx.DisplayMember = "value";
           }
```

---